# Leaving Spain meanwhile the application is pending

Tags: eu-spouses, spain

I am trying to look for more info, but I don't see any evident guideline.

Spanish national, is going to require a family reunification visa for her non-eu spouse. They travel to Spain and make the application.

Could they travel abroad meanwhile the application is pending? I am aware about the "autorizacion de regreso" but that form only applies for the TIE, not for the initial residence application.